# How can i delete a single comment for a user inside of a post in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I'm trying to add a delete button for a single comment of current user inside a post. I tried the function below in my views.py , but it comes back as error: Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/comments/15/delete/
Raised by:  feed.views.comment_delete

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong ?

views.py

```
@login_required
def comment_delete(request, pk):
    comment = get_object_or_404(Comments, pk=pk)
    if request.user.id == comment.username_id:
        Comments.objects.get(pk=pk).delete()
        messages.error(request, f'Comment Deleted')
    return redirect('post-detail', pk=pk)
```

models.py

```
class Post(models.Model):
    description = models.TextField(max_length=255)
    pic = models.ImageField(upload_to='path/to/img', blank=True)
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    user_name = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    tags = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)

    def __str__(self): 
        return self.description

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('post-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})
 

class Comments(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, related_name='details', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    username = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='details', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    comment = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    comment_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
```

post_detail.html

```
        <h4 class="comment_text">Comments</h4>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xl-9 col-md-10 m-auto order-xl-2 mb-0 mb-xl-0">
                {% if post.details.all %}
                <div class="card card-signin my-0">
                {% for detail in post.details.all %}
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <a href="{{ detail.username.profile.get_absolute_url }}">
                            <img src="{{ detail.username.profile.image.url }}" class="rounded-circle" width="30" height="30" alt="">
                        </a>
                        <a class="text-dark" href="{{ detail.username.profile.get_absolute_url }}"><b>{{ detail.username }}</b></a>
                         <a class="comment_delete" href="{% url "comment-delete" user.id %}">delete</a>
                        
                        <br><small>{{ detail.comment_date }}</small><br><br>
                        <p class="card-text text-dark">{{ detail.comment }}</p>
                    </div>
                    <hr class="my-1">
                {% endfor %}
                </div>
                {% else %}
                    <p>No comments to show!</p>
                {% endif %}
            </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

In your template you write `{% url "comment-delete" user.id %}` when in fact the argument that the view expects is the **comments** id/pk. Change it to `{% url "comment-delete" detail.pk %}`

Comment: Thanks ,  'detail.pk'  worked i also wanted to redirect back to my post-detail page and my redirect in views.py was not working so i added : return HttpResponseRedirect(request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER')) , at end of comment_delete in views.py  so after I delete the comment it comes straight back to the same post_detail page.